# Python random terminal 0

Tags: python

I am currently writing a Py script that uses

```
    import os
    newinput = raw_input(os.system("echo '\033[4;35m Hello \033[0m'")
```

But straight after that,
I get this random zero And I can't seem to get rid of it

it looks like this

```
    user@user$ Hello 0
```

How do I get rid of this?

Comment: What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: FWIW I think that 0 is the status code of the command

Comment: You _execute_ the `echo` command, then _print_ the return value of that command, i.e. the exit code `0` for "exited with no error".

Comment: Yes, but I am using this to return something, and this zero keeps getting in the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you just want to have a colorful input, you can get rid of the `os.system` call and just do:

```
newinput = raw_input("\033[4;35m Hello \033[0m")
```

Comment: Just wondering, do the ANSI escapes apply to all, or in this instance, like I printed out the same string in C, would it output the same color?

Comment: And it still seems to return zero if I do something like                                                catme = os.system("cat catme.txt")

Answer (score 5):

You are calling `raw_input` with the return value of `os.system()` as its argument. `echo` is returning an exit status of 0. `raw_input` prints its argument, so it is printing 0.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you miss a ")" at the end of the second row.